# Reading each line of input from file and assign to a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to read each line of input from a file, take a particular word(seperating by a delimiter) and assign it to a variable.

```
cat Number
Number11,Number21,Number31
Number12,Number22,Number32
Number13,Number23,Number33
```

I used the following code:

```
while
read LINE
do
var1=$(echo $LINE|awk -F, '{ print $1 }')
echo $var1
done < Number|awk -F\, '{ print $1 "," $2 }'|head -2
```

I want the output to be:

```
Number11
Number12
Number13
```

But I got the output as:

```
Number11,
Number12,
Number13,
```

I am getting comma(,) which is not required. Can some one correct me.

Answer (score 3):

Answered many times...

```
while IFS=, read -r n1 n2 n3
do
    #echo "=n1:$n1= =n2:$n2= =n3:$n3="
    echo "$n1"
done < Number
```

- it sets the `IFS` (input field separator) to comma
- read the file line-by-line
- assing fields (splitted by IFS) into the variables at `read`'s argument

prints:

```
Number11
Number12
Number13
```

Comment: And since only the first field is needed, `n3` can be removed as the  `n2` variable will absorb the remaining fields.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
#read the lines as array with delemiter as ','
while IFS=',' read -a line
do
  # echo the index zero of the array
  echo "${line[0]}"
done < Number
```

Answer (score 0):

`cut` is also useful for this case:

```
while read LINE; do 
   var1=$(cut -d ',' -f 1 <<< $LINE)
   echo $var1
done < Number
```

Output:

```
Number11
Number12
Number13
```

Comment: While `cut` works, there's no reason to use it, since `read` can perform the exact same field-splitting without resorting to an external command.

Comment: True, it's more of a personal preference as well. This is good to know though.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `awk` command:

```
awk -F"," '{print $1}' Number
```

This avoids an unnecessary loop to read the file line by line since awk will anyway parse the file line by line. `-F` option of awk is used to specify the delimiter.

Since you want it to be in a variable, try this:

```
for each in `awk -F"," '{print $1}' Number`
do
   echo $each
done
```